# Как сделать пробел (или перевод строки)?

Tags: php

не получается сделать пробел в php скрипте. У меня вот такой код:

```
echo $data['name'] . '->' . $data['recipient'] . ':' . $data['mess'];
```

Comment: @sasha-osipov2, вам нужно пробел или перенос строки?

Comment: Из вопроса мало что понятно, могу лишь предположить что вы вставляете символы переноса в одинарные кавычки.
Надо так:

    echo ''. $data['name'] . '->' . $data['recipient'] . ':' . $data['mess'] ."\r\n";

Comment: Мне нужен был перенос строки. Спасибо, работает!

Comment: PHP_EOL в конце строки после конкотенации)

Comment: Есть замечательная функция `nl2br`. Кстати в `html` не работает `PHP_EOL` - то есть `\n` или `\r` - это работает только в `text/plain`.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы выводить данные из РНР в браузер, надо мало-мало учить **HTML.** Поскольку за форматирование выводимых в браузер данных отвечает именно этот язык разметки.
А чтобы получить ответ на свой вопрос в интернете, надо учить *русский* язык, поскольку разные слова имеют разный смысл, и если вы хотите, чтобы вас поняли, не следует заменять одни слова другими.

- Чтобы вывести *пробел*, надо просто нажать соответствующую клавишу на клавиатуре:

  ```
  echo $name . ' ' . $recipient;
  ```

  и между содержимым переменных $name $recipient будет отображен пробел
- чтобы вывести *неразрывный пробел,* можно использовать HTML-сущность `&nbsp;`
- чтобы *перенести строку в HTML*, можно использовать любой из десятков тегов, которые визуально отделяют строки друг от друга. Самым простым из них является `<br />` (после которого желательно добавлять символ перевода строки, чтобы потом можно было нормально читать исходник страницы).
- чтобы вывести перевод строки, можно использовать константу PHP_EOL или же не париться и просто использовать символ "\n" в двойных кавычках.

Answer (score -1):

Пробел в PHP - добавьте в строку: `&nbsp;`

Answer (score -1):

Ну если рендерить через echo, тогда

```
<?
echo "&npsp";
?>
```

Comment: Не слишком похоже на актуальный и полезный ответ для вопроса девятилетней давности, к тому же с опечаткой - должно быть `&nbsp;`

Answer (score -2):

Короче говоря для тех кто запутался в этом:
пробел это      `. "" .`

например      `echo "В запросе затронуто" . "" . mysqli_affected_rows($a) . "" . "строк из базы данных" ;`

Comment: В вопросе все же речь о переносе строки, как я понял.

Comment: та да я так полагаю нужно парню подсказать что нужно вставить в конце PHP_EOL